# Android Full screen videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to like youtube like full screen video shrink and expand on click full size video click on fullscreen imagebutton I want to video screen full size I use fragment.

my videoplayer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videolayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >


        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mediaController"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone" >


        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnpalypause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
             />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/maximize" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

just tell me on fullscreen image button click event what i do...

Answer (score 0):

To show on full screen :

after tap on full size button hide all video controller view.

but you can use below link for you tube player :

https://github.com/Jungerr/Demo-YouTuBe-Android

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: But yogendra i want to use custom player not to youtube  just tell how to implement fullscreen feature in my activity  .....

Comment: or full screen use landscape and hide other view like controller and all.

Comment: @Yogendra  i also tried to hide controller and other views but still my video is not appearing as full screen in landscape

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about immersive visibility.

You can do this by setting the visibility as follows:

```
myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Be sure to set an OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener to monitor when the user has touched the screen or otherwise forced themselves out of full screen immersive mode.

This is also only available in API 21 and up.

To force landscape view, create a new activity and update the settings in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="FullscreenVideoActivity" />
```

Then block orientation changes by overriding the config changes function in FullScreenActivity.java with an empty function.

```
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{      
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 
}
```

Comment: Yes u getting my point.... but it's require to set SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ?

Comment: For that, I would use another activity with just the video view and force it to landscape through the manifest.